# _create function in custom require.js not called

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I am creating a custom js for my module.

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myjs:'Namespace_Module/js/myjs'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/js/myjs.js**

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "jquery/ui"
],
    function($, _){
        console.log('1');
        $.widget('mage.myjs', {
            options: {
                divId: '',
                ajaxUrl: '',
                isNeedLast: false,
                autoSubmit: false,
            },
            selects: [],
        _create: function() {
            console.log('inside create'); // this log is not displayed
        }
    });

    return $.mage.myjs;

});
```

and calling it in the phtml like below :

```
require(['jquery', 'myjs'], function($) {
        var finderConfig = {"ajaxUrl":"<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>","isNeedLast":1,"autoSubmit":1};
        finderConfig.divId = 'finder_<?php echo $finderID ?>';
        $("#finder").myjs(finderConfig);
    });
```

here the `console.log('1')` is displayed but the `console.log('inside create')` inside `_create` function is not displayed.

cany anyone point out what i am missing.Thanks.

Comment: check https://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2016/02/27/how-to-add-custom-javascript-in-magento-2/

Comment: it is still not working @SohelRana

Comment: Have you use some code in your phtml file ?

Comment: @SHPatel Yes, check the edited question.

Comment: Have you created div with id="finder" in your phtml code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your phtml file.

```
<div id="finder"></div>
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'myjs'], function($) {
        var finderConfig = {"ajaxUrl":"<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>","isNeedLast":1,"autoSubmit":1};
        finderConfig.divId = 'finder_<?php echo $finderID ?>';
        $("#finder").myjs(finderConfig);
    });
</script>
```

I think you are missing div with id="finder" in your code. please check it with this code.

let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: yes ur correct i was accessing the class with `#` instead of `.` thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/js/myjs.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "jquery/ui"
],
function ($) {
    'use strict';
        console.log('1');
        $.widget('mage.myjs', {
            options: {
                divId: '',
                ajaxUrl: '',
                isNeedLast: false,
                autoSubmit: false,
            },
        _create: function() {
            console.log('inside create');
        }
    });
    return $.mage.myjs;
});
```

and calling it in the phtml like below :

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "myjs": {
                    "divId": "finder_" + <?php echo json_encode($finderID) ?>,
                    "ajaxUrl": <?php echo json_encode($block->getAjaxUrl()) ?>,
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```